# How to display the column number of columns of numbers with vim

Tags: vim, number-formatting, cursor-position

I have a file with only columns of numbers separated by blank spaces. Something like this :

```
 0.0000000000   21.8066943617    0.0000000000
21.9391475974    0.0000000000   22.5951998271
 0.0000000000   22.7253887380    0.0000000000
```

How can I display the current column number of the cursor in Vim. Not the column of each character but the column number of columns of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach: This grabs the text of the current line, up to the cursor position, then performs text manipulation to condense each text column into a single character, then counts the characters.

```
:let textBeforeCursor = strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1)
:let reduceColumnToSingleChar = substitute(textBeforeCursor, '\s*\S*', 'x', 'g')
:echo len(reduceColumnToSingleChar)
```

If you put this into a `:function`, it can be easily invoked by a mapping.

If you change the `:echo` to `:return`, you can even include this in your `'statusline'` (via `set statusline+=\ %{ColumnCount()}`), so that it updates as you move around the buffer.